# numpy array row major and column major

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having trouble understanding how `numpy` stores its data. Consider the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ndarray(shape=(2,3), order='F')
>>> for i in xrange(6): a.itemset(i, i+1)
... 
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
>>> a.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

This says that `a` is column major (`F_CONTIGUOUS`) thus, internally, `a` should look like the following:

```
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

This is just what it is stated in in this [glossary](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-column-major). What is confusing me is that if I try to to access the data of `a` in a linear fashion instead I get:

```
>>> for i in xrange(6): print a.item(i)
... 
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
```

At this point I'm not sure what the `F_CONTIGUOUS` flag tells us since it does not honor the ordering. Apparently everything in python is row major and when we want to iterate in a linear fashion we can use the iterator [`flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#flat-iterator-indexing).

**The question is the following:** given that we have a list of numbers, say: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, how can we create a `numpy` array of shape `(2, 3)` in column major order? That is how can I get a matrix that looks like this

```
array([[ 1.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  6.]])
```

I would really like to be able to iterate linearly over the list and place them into the newly created `ndarray`. The reason for this is because I will be reading files of multidimensional arrays set in column major order.

Comment: can you just reshape?

Comment: @dvreed77 reshape only change the shape, not the order

Comment: I have check the doc of reshape, it says 'order : {'C', 'F', 'A'}, optional
        Determines whether the array data should be viewed as in C
        (row-major) order, FORTRAN (column-major) order, or the C/FORTRAN
        order should be preserved.' So I guess it just change the view, not the order it stores.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The numpy stores data in row major order.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 4)
>>> a.shape = 4,2
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

If you change the shape, the order of data do not change.

If you add a 'F', you can get what you want.

```
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> c = b.reshape(2,3,order='F')
>>> c
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

Comment: The order is the one that needs to change. I guess there is no other way around it. I have to accept that matlab does column major and python is row major. Is there nothing better than creating a `(3, 2)` array and then use `transpose`?

Comment: @jmlopez You can provide a keyword argument `order` when making an array. If it's already created you can use the `.reshape(order=...)` method. Info here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Comment: @jmlopez Only use that to convert Matlab data to numpy format. You should keep the standard numpy order or data may be copied when applying numpy's functions.

Comment: F is for Fortran. They have an array type which is columnar.

Answer (score 35):

Your question has been answered, but I thought I would add this to explain your observations regarding, *"At this point I'm not sure what the `F_CONTIGUOUS` flag tells us since it does not honor the ordering."*

---

The `item` method doesn't directly access the data like you think it does. To do this, you should access the `data` attribute, which gives you the byte string.

An example:

```
c = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,6,7]], order='C')

f = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,6,7]], order='F')
```

Observe

```
print c.flags.c_contiguous, f.flags.f_contiguous
# True, True
```

and

```
print c.nbytes == len(c.data)
# True
```

Now let's print the contiguous data for both:

```
nelements = np.prod(c.shape)
bsize = c.dtype.itemsize # should be 8 bytes for 'int64'
for i in range(nelements):
    bnum = c.data[i*bsize : (i+1)*bsize] # The element as a byte string.
    print np.fromstring(bnum, dtype=c.dtype)[0], # Convert to number.
```

This prints:

```
1 2 3 4 6 7
```

which is what we expect since `c` is order `'C'`, i.e., its data is stored row-major contiguous.

On the other hand,

```
nelements = np.prod(f.shape)
bsize = f.dtype.itemsize # should be 8 bytes for 'int64'
for i in range(nelements):
    bnum = f.data[i*bsize : (i+1)*bsize] # The element as a byte string.
    print np.fromstring(bnum, dtype=f.dtype)[0], # Convert to number.
```

prints

```
1 4 2 6 3 7
```

which, again, is what we expect to see since `f`'s data is stored column-major contiguous.

Comment: I like this answer, but `np.fromstring` doesn't work like this anymore in Python3, resulting in **TypeError: fromstring() argument 1 must be read-only bytes-like object, not memoryview**.

Instead I tried using `frombuffer` as in `print(np.frombuffer(bnum, dtype=f.dtype))`, which worked for the row-order data, but failed for the column-order data with **BufferError: memoryview: underlying buffer is not C-contiguous**.

So I'm not yet sure how to confirm underlying data order as described here.

Comment: not that it matters for validity of your example, but why did you leave the 5 out?

Answer (score 9):

Wanted to add this in the comments but my rep is too low:

While Kill Console's answer gave the OP's required solution, I think it's important to note that as stated in the numpy.reshape() documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

> Note there is no guarantee of the memory layout (C- or Fortran- contiguous) of the returned array.

so even if the view is column-wise, the data itself may not be, which may lead to inefficiencies in calculations which benefit from the data being stored column-wise in memory. Perhaps:

```
a = np.array(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).reshape(2,3,order='F'), order='F')
```

provides more of a guarantee that the data is stored column-wise (see order argument description at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Answer (score 4):

In general, numpy uses order to describe the memory layout, but the python behavior of the arrays should be consistent regardless of the memory layout. I think you can get the behavior you want using views. A view is an array that shares memory with another array. For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 6 + 1)
b = a.reshape(3, 2).T

a[1] = 99
print b
# [[ 1  3  5]
#  [99  4  6]]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to print the data in memory order, by using the `ravel()` function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ndarray(shape=(2,3), order='F')
>>> for i in range(6): a.itemset(i, i+1)

>>> print(a.ravel(order='K'))
[ 1.  4.  2.  5.  3.  6.]
```

This confirms that the array is stored in Fortran order.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but I feel the answer is missing.

Just to mention a couple functions that have not been mentioned:

```py
a = np.ascontiguousarray(in_arr)
b = np.asfortranarray(in_arr)
```

However, they will not help with your problem. What will help:

```
a = np.ndarray(shape=(2,3), order='F')
def memory_index(*args, x):
    idx = (np.array(x.strides) / a.itemsize).dot(np.array(args))
    return int(idx)

flat_view = a.ravel(order='A')   # or order='F' to be explicit
for i, value in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
    flat_view[i] = value

print(a)
```

array([[ 1.,  3.,  5.],
[ 2.,  4.,  6.]])

Obviously, factor out repetitive tasks from `memory_index`, use simple arithmetics instead of the `dot` function and it might just be reasonably fast to be worth it.