# Reshaping in julia

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, reshape, julia

If I reshape in python I use this:

```
import numpy as np

y= np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
x=2
z=y.reshape(-1, x)


print(z)
```

and get this

```
>>> 
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]
 [7 8]]
```

How would I get the same thing in julia? I tried:

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x= 2
a=reshape(z,x,4)

println(a)
```

and it gave me:

```
[1 3 5 7
 2 4 6 8]
```

If I use `reshape(z,4,x)` it would give

```
[1 5
 2 6
 3 7
 4 8]
```

Also is there a way to do reshape without specifying the second dimension like `reshape(z,x)` or if the secondary dimension is more ambiguous?

Comment: `reshape(z,4,x)` would seem like what you want, no?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski No that will give [1,5] as the first two numbers not  [1,2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x = 2
a = reshape(z,x,4)'
```

which gives

```
julia> a = reshape(z,x,4)'
4x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
 7  8
```

As for your bonus question

> "Also is there a way to do reshape without specifying the second
>   dimension like reshape(z,x) or if the secondary dimension is more
>   ambiguous?"

the answer is not exactly, because it'd be ambiguous: `reshape` can make 3D, 4D, ..., tensors so its not clear what is expected. You can, however, do something like

```
matrix_reshape(z,x) = reshape(z, x, div(length(z),x))
```

which does what I think you expect.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you have hit upon is [NumPy stores in row-major order](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-column-major) and [Julia stores arrays in column major order](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#implementation) as covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341614/numpy-array-row-major-and-column-major).

So Julia is doing what numpy would do if you used

```
z=y.reshape(-1,x,order='F')
```

what you want is the transpose of your first attempt, which is

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x= 2
a=reshape(z,x,4)'

println(a)
```

you want to know if there is something that will compute the 2nd dimension assuming the array is 2 dimensional?  Not that I know of.  Possibly [ArrayViews](https://github.com/JuliaLang/ArrayViews.jl)? Here's a simple function to start

```
julia> shape2d(x,shape...)=length(shape)!=1?reshape(x,shape...):reshape(x,shape[1],Int64(length(x)/shape[1]))
shape2d (generic function with 1 method)

julia> shape2d(z,x)'
4x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
 7  8
```

Comment: So if one of the python libraries I use has `reshape` in python I guess it would be difficult to switch it over to julia without using Arrayview? Seems like there should be a built in linear algebra method for this.

Answer (score 1):

> "Also is there a way to do reshape without specifying the second dimension like reshape(z,x) or if the secondary dimension is more ambiguous?"

**Use `:` instead of `-1`**

I'm using Julia 1.1 (not sure if there was a feature when it was originally answered)

```
julia> z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; a = reshape(z,:,2)
4×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5
 2  6
 3  7
 4  8
```

However, if you want the first row to be `1 2` and match Python, you'll need to follow the other answer mentioning row-major vs column-major ordering and do

```
julia> z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; a = reshape(z,2,:)'
4×2 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
 7  8
```