# MATLAB to Python conversion: vectors, arrays, index elements

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, type-conversion, data-conversion

Good day to everyone! I'm currently converting a MATLAB project to Python 2.7. I am trying to convert the line

```matlab
h =  [  im(:,2:cols)  zeros(rows,1) ] - [  zeros(rows,1)  im(:,1:cols-1)  ];
```

When I try to convert it

```py
h = np.concatenate((im[1,range(2,cols)], np.zeros((rows, 1)))) -  
np.concatenate((np.zeros((rows, 1)),im[1,range(2,cols - 1)] ))
```

IDLE returns different errors like

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I'm very new to Python and I would appreciate it if you would suggest other methods. Thank you so much! Here's the function I am trying to convert.

```matlab
function [gradient, or] = canny(im, sigma, scaling, vert, horz)
xscaling = vert; yscaling = horz;
hsize = [6*sigma+1, 6*sigma+1];   % The filter size.

gaussian = fspecial('gaussian',hsize,sigma);
im = filter2(gaussian,im);        % Smoothed image.

im = imresize(im, scaling, 'AntiAliasing',false);

[rows, cols] = size(im);

h =  [  im(:,2:cols)  zeros(rows,1) ] - [  zeros(rows,1)  im(:,1:cols-1)  ];
```

***And I also would ask the equivalent of ':' operator that is used mainly in indeces and arrays in Python. Is there any equivalent for the : operator?***

The Python converted code I started:

```py
def canny(im=None, sigma=None, scaling=None, vert=None, horz=None):

xscaling = vert
yscaling = horz

hsize = (6 * sigma + 1), (6 * sigma + 1) # The filter size.

gaussian = gauss2D(hsize, sigma)
im = filter2(gaussian, im) # Smoothed image.
print("This is im")
print(im)
print("This is hsize")
print(hsize)
print("This is scaling")
print(scaling)
#scaling = 0.4
#scaling = tuple(scaling)

im = cv2.resize(im,None, fx=scaling, fy=scaling )  
[rows, cols] = np.shape(im)
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your data is in a list of lists. Try this:

```
a = [[2, 9, 4], [7, 5, 3], [6, 1, 8]]
im = np.array(a, dtype=float)
rows = 3
cols = 3
h = (np.hstack([im[:, 1:cols], np.zeros((rows, 1))])
   - np.hstack([np.zeros((rows, 1)), im[:, :cols-1]]))
```

The equivalent of MATLAB's [horzcat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) (that is, `[A B]`) is [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and the equivalent of [vertcat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) (`[A; B]`) is [np.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

[Array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html) in numpy is very close to MATLAB, except that indexes start at 0 in numpy, and the range p:q means "p to q-1".

Also, the storage order of arrays is [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) by default, and you can use column-major order if you want (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341614/numpy-array-row-major-and-column-major)). In MATLAB, arrays are stored in column-major order. To check in Python, type for instance `np.isfortran(im)`. If it returns true, the array has the same order as MATLAB (Fortran order), otherwise it's row-major (C order). It's important when you want to optimize loops, or when you pass an array to a C or Fortran routine.

Ideally, try to put everything in an np.array as soon as possible, and don't use lists (they take much more space and processing is much slower). There are also some quirks: for instance, `1.0 / 0.0` throws an exception, but `np.float64(1.0) / np.float64(0.0)` returns `inf`, like in MATLAB.

---

Another example from the comments:

```
d1 = [ im(2:rows,2:cols) zeros(rows-1,1); zeros(1,cols) ] - ...
     [ zeros(1,cols); zeros(rows-1,1) im(1:rows-1,1:cols-1) ];

d2 = [ zeros(1,cols); im(1:rows-1,2:cols) zeros(rows-1,1); ] - ... 
     [ zeros(rows-1,1) im(2:rows,1:cols-1); zeros(1,cols) ];
```

For this one, rather than np.vstack and np.hstack, you can use [np.block](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html).

```
im = np.ones((10, 15))
rows, cols = im.shape

d1 = (np.block([[im[1:rows, 1:cols], np.zeros((rows-1, 1))],
                [np.zeros((1, cols))]]) -
      np.block([[np.zeros((1, cols))],
                [np.zeros((rows-1, 1)), im[:rows-1, :cols-1]]]))

d2 = (np.block([[np.zeros((1, cols))],
                [im[:rows-1, 1:cols], np.zeros((rows-1, 1))]]) -
      np.block([[np.zeros((rows-1, 1)), im[1:rows, :cols-1]],
                [np.zeros((1, cols))]]))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184837/discussion-on-answer-by-jean-claude-arbaut-matlab-to-python-conversion-vectors).

Comment: I tried and used the d2 you put in the answer but I'm still getting the error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (78,103) (78,104) I also image-hosted the IDLE screenshot and my code for also convenient code-reading ibb.co/xYdybcx

Comment: @PauloEstrella The problem comes from the line `X = (h + (d1 + d2) / 2.0) * xscaling`. Check the shape of arguments (especially `h`). Until you master the dimensions and indexes of numpy arrays, I suggets you don't just run a program but check each line line by line in an interactive Python session, and check the shape and contents of every variable, and when in doubt, of subexpressions. Then you will find right away when and why it fails.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Arbaut I just printed the values of variables h,v,d1,d2 it turns out that the variable 'h', was the culprit of the error which returns the shape '(112L, 127L)' while the rest of the variables returns '(111L, 128L)'

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut could it be because of the line of code you created for variable 'h'?

Comment: I have now solved I just checked the dimensions in h and v. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

With np.zeros((Nrows,1)) you are generating a 2D array containing Nrows 1D arrays with 1 element. Then, with im[1,2:cols] your are getting a 1D array of cols-2 elements. You should change np.zeros((rows,1)) by np.zeros(rows).

Moreover, at the second np.concatenate, when you get a subarray from 'im' you should take the same number of elements than in the first concatenate. Note that you are taking one element less: range(2,cols) VS range(2,cols-1).

Comment: You should start from the MATLAB code, as the Python attempt is obviously not equivalent.