# Setting a numpy array value at an index in c++ with pybind

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I can read the value of an 4-dimensional numpy array defined by

```
py::array_t<double> data;
```

at the location [37,36,24,1] with

```
data.at(37,36,24,1);
```

How can I set the value at that location?

(This attempt did not seem to change the correct element, with the convention [x,y,z,q];

```
py::buffer_info buff_info = data.request();
((double*) buff_info.ptr)[(x * buff_info.shape[1] * buff_info.shape[2] * buff_info.shape[3]) + (y * buff_info.shape[2] * buff_info.shape[3]) + (z  * buff_info.shape[3]) + q] = 17;
```

)

Comment: hello Omroth, it works on my machine, did you make sure to instantiate a 4D array?

Comment: Sorry, it did compile and run fine, but did not get the right element... when I read the element back in python it didnt show my change

Comment: Humm, that's weird, in my case it changed the correct element. Could you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341959/3283333) that uses Fortran's column-major ordering and see if it changes ?

Comment: Hi Omroth, did you solve your issue? If not, could you provide also your python code to see the way you test things ?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at it again yet, will report back when I do.