# how does memory allocation occur in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)

for i in a:
    print("Id of {} : {} \n".format(i,id(i)))
```

**>>>>**

Id of 0 : 2295176255984

Id of 1 : 2295176255696

Id of 2 : 2295176255984

Id of 3 : 2295176255696

Id of 4 : 2295176255984

I want to understand how the elements of numpy array are being allocated in the memory, which I understand is different from that of Python arrays seeing the output.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Having native C bindings, the default allocation scheme is row-major. But you can change that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341614/numpy-array-row-major-and-column-major and study row-major and column-major allocation schemes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [68]: arr = np.arange(5)
In [69]: arr
Out[69]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

One way of viewing the attributes of a numpy array is:

```
In [70]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[70]: 
{'data': (139628245945184, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (5,),
 'version': 3}
```

`data` is something like the `id` of its data buffer, where the values are actually stored.  We can't use this number in other code, but it is useful when checking for things like `view`. The rest is used to interpret those values.

The `memory` for `arr` is a `c` array 40 bytes long (5*8) somewhere.  That where does not matter to us.  Any `view` of `arr` will work with the same data buffer.  a `copy` will have its own data buffer.

Iterating on the array is like accessing values one by one:

```
In [71]: i = arr[1]
In [72]: i
Out[72]: 1
In [73]: type(i)
Out[73]: numpy.int64
```

This `i` is not a reference to an element of `a`.  It is new object with the **same value**.  It's a lot like a 0d array, with many of the same attributes, including:

```
In [74]: i.__array_interface__
Out[74]: 
{'data': (25251568, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (),
 'version': 3,
 '__ref': array(1)}
```

This is why you can't make much sense from looking at the `id` in the iteration.  It is also why iterating on a numpy array is slower than iterating on list.  We strongly discourage iteration like this.

Contrast that with a list, where elements are stored (in some sort of data buffer) by **reference**:

```
In [78]: a,b,c = 100,'b',{}
In [79]: id(a)
Out[79]: 9788064
In [80]: alist=[a,b,c]
In [81]: id(alist[0])
Out[81]: 9788064
```

The list actually contains `a`, or if you prefer a reference to the same object that the variable `a` references.  Remember, Python is object oriented all the way down.

In sum, Python lists contain references.  Numpy arrays contain values, which its own methods access and manipulate.  There is an object dtype that does contain references, but let's not go there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Code with Mosh. He teaches all such kind of things on his youtube channel as well as udemy. I've purchased his udemy course on Data structures and Algorithms which goes deep into how something works.
For example, while teaching about an array, he shows how to make an array so as to understand the underlying concepts behind it.

You can take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBpAmxU_NQo

If you're only interested in knowing about only the NumPy array:

First I'll tell you about the differences:

**Difference between NumPy and an Array**

Numpy is the core library for scientific computing in Python. It provides a high-performance multidimensional array object and tools for working with these arrays. A NumPy array is a grid of values, all of the same type, and is indexed by a tuple of nonnegative integers. The number of dimensions is the rank of the array; the shape of an array is a tuple of integers giving the size of the array along each dimension.

The Python core library provided Lists. A list is the Python equivalent of an array, but is resizeable and can contain elements of different types.

A common beginner question is what is the real difference here. The answer is performance. Numpy data structures perform better in:

Size - Numpy data structures take up less space
Performance - they have a need for speed and are faster than lists
Functionality - SciPy and NumPy have optimized functions such as linear algebra operations built-in.

Another key notable difference is in how they store and make use of memory
**Memory**

The main benefits of using NumPy arrays should be smaller memory consumption and better runtime behaviour.

[image: Image of how python lists work]

For Python Lists -  We can conclude from this that for every new element, we need another eight bytes for the reference to the new object. The new integer object itself consumes 28 bytes.

[image: Image of how NumPy works]
NumPy takes up less space. This means that an arbitrary integer array of length "n" in NumPy needs

If you are curious and want me to prove that NumPy really takes less time:

```
# importing required packages 
import numpy 
import time 

# size of arrays and lists 
size = 1000000

# declaring lists 
list1 = range(size) 
list2 = range(size) 

# declaring arrays 
array1 = numpy.arange(size) 
array2 = numpy.arange(size) 

# capturing time before the multiplication of Python lists 
initialTime = time.time() 

# multiplying elements of both the lists and stored in another list 
resultantList = [(a * b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)] 

# calculating execution time 
print("Time taken by Lists to perform multiplication:", 
    (time.time() - initialTime), 
    "seconds") 

# capturing time before the multiplication of Numpy arrays 
initialTime = time.time() 

# multiplying elements of both the Numpy arrays and stored in another Numpy array 
resultantArray = array1 * array2 

# calculating execution time 
print("Time taken by NumPy Arrays to perform multiplication:", 
    (time.time() - initialTime), 
    "seconds")
```

**Output:**

```
Time taken by Lists : 0.15030384063720703 seconds
Time taken by NumPy Arrays : 0.005921125411987305 seconds
```

**Wait.. There is a very big disadvantage too:**

Requires continuous allocation of memory -
Insertion and deletion operations can become costly as data is stored in contiguous memory locations as shifting it requires shifting.

If you want to learn more about numpy:
https://www.educba.com/introduction-to-numpy/

You can thank me later!