# polars - what does "fortran-like indexing" mean and how to enforce it?

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars, zero-copy

I am trying to use `to_numpy(allow_copy=False)` on my polars dataframe, but I am getting:

`RuntimeError: copy not allowed: only numeric data without nulls in Fortran-like order can be converted without copy`

Since I checked that `df.select(pl.all().is_null().sum())` gives 0 for every column (I have 3), I suppose that the problem is in the fortran-like indexing. How to enforce it?

I would also like to know what does the fortran-like indexing mean for polars (I failed to find any sources on that).

I was unfortunately not able to reproduce an example since the zero copy mode works just fine for basic examples and my data creation process is a too long to reproduce.

The exception also raises for `order = "c"` and `writable = False` options.

EDIT: After some thinking I decided to reformulate this question in more general form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78039906/polars-is-there-a-procedure-that-ensures-zero-copy-when-calling-df-to-numpy).

Comment: I'm not familiar with polars, but I'd bet that "Fortran-like order" means [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341614/numpy-array-row-major-and-column-major

Comment: We'd need a [mcve] to understand what you mean by "polars dataframe."  Also maybe I'm reading the documentation wrong, but `to_numpy()` doesn't seem to be a documented method of the `DataFrame` data type, only of `Series`.

Comment: . . . ok, looking through `python-polars` tag, it seems like this only *looks* like a `pandas` question. My mistake, that I'll document here lest anyone else get confused.

Comment: How about `order='F'` option?

Comment: Did you read and understand the `to_numpy` docs?  Is your data all numeric (no strings)?  Quite likely the data is stored in a column oriented sense (Series in pandas terms).  If so a no-copy array will have a `F' order.

Comment: `order = 'F'` returns the same error.

Comment: The dtype of each column is `f32`, number of nulls is 0. I read the docs, but it only says what each option do, not how, nor why.