# Polars: Is there a procedure that ensures zero copy when calling df.to_numpy()?

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars, zero-copy

For some time now I am failing to call `df.to_numpy(allow_copy = True)`.
Is there a procedure that transforms any given dataset into "zero_copy suitable" one?

For list-like values I tried

```
data = pl.DataFrame(dict(
    points=np.random.sample((N, 3)),
    color=np.random.sample((N, 4))
),
schema=dict(
    points=pl.Array(pl.Float64, 3),
    color=pl.Array(pl.Float64, 4),
))
```

or simply `expr.cast(pl.Array(pl.Float32, 4))` as suggested [here](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/5516). It works for one of my datasets, but fails for a different one with slightly different build .

Calling `rechunk()`, having no null values and/or specifying `order = "c"` or `"fortran"` also seems to have no effect.

This is a generalization of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78025987/polars-what-does-fortran-like-indexing-mean-and-how-to-enforce-it?noredirect=1#comment137560472_78025987) that was perhaps too specific to get a real answer.

Answer (score 4):

No, that operation would copy itself. Numpy matrices are contiguously allocated in a single allocation. Where Polars mostly contiguously allocated per column. That means that if memory is allocated by Polars, it cannot be transferred zero-copy to a numpy 2D matrix.

Polars columns and Polars Array types can be moved zero-copy to numpy.

## Moving data from numpy to Polars and back.

A 2D matrix from numpy in fortran order, can be moved zero-copy to Polars and again zero-copy back to numpy. This works because the original numpy allocation will not be changed. All Polars columns point into the numpy contiguous array memory.

### Why only F-order?

Because Polars is a columnar query engine, we only store `F-contiguous` data. Otherwise we would need to skip rows on column traversal. This would duplicate all code, or add an indirection for traversal which would be much slower.

Aside from that, you now have `row` values in your cache line, making all columnar algorithms much much slower.

### C-contiguous

In c-contiguous, row values are back to back. If we need `column_value` we must skip `n` `row_x` slots, where `n` is proportional on the number of columns.

```
[column_value_1, row_x, row_x, ...,  row_x, column_value_2]
```

### F-contiguous

In f-contiguous, column slots are back to back, leading to fast cache efficient reading

```
[column_value_1, column_value_2, ..., column_value_n]
```

So zero-copy `C-contiguous` data `DataFrames` comes with a performance cost for most operations (which are columnar) and might even trigger a copy if underlying columnar algorithms expect slices with data back to back (which isn't far fetched).

### TLDR;

DataFrame implementations that support zero-copy of c-order data pay a price with cache trashing or make implicit copies if the algorithms expect a slice.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation! I understand that there is no way to transform a dataset to zero_copy to_numpy without copying data. But what about LazyFrames? I am doig many calculations in Polars lazyframe because of performance and i only call .collect() right before the to_numpy transformation. Is there a possibility to specify ordering before .collect()? What would be the cost of performance?

Comment: Or what about column by column approach? Would that be a solution?

Comment: Columns can be zero-copy in both directions. If the data is numeric and you don't have nulls, it is zero copy.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on ritchie46's answer in a way that I understand it.

Let's start with this table

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
a   b   c
```

(Let's say abc is 10, 11, 12 respectively not that we're mixing numbers and letters)

Computer memory doesn't have dimensions so when we say that it is columnar storage it means that the computer sees that as data=`147a258b369c` and offsets=`048` where the data is each column and the offsets tell it where new columns start for us humans to look at.

In row oriented storage it will have data=`123456789abc` and offsets=`0369`.

Why would one framework/library/software use columnar while another uses row based?

Well think about something like a database of customers where you learn the customer's first name, last name, and address at the same time so you store that at once. A database is row oriented so that when you put that new record in, it goes together.

Of course when you want to analyze data it's usually the opposite, for instance if you want to know how many customers live in each state then the only thing you want is the address column. To analyze the column in row oriented storage means it has to refer to the offset and pluck out each of those locations from the data. On the other hand if it were column oriented data then it could just get the *range* of the data rather than having to pluck at what amounts to random locations.

The reason it must be copied is that each library is optimized around the assumption that data is organized contiguously (polars/array can have chunks that are discontinuous but within the chunks they're still continuous) in row or column order. You can't just tell numpy ok here's some column oriented data you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. The more I read the more I think that there should be no problem for Series.to_numpy(). It should be continuous data regardless the rows/column order. Yet it seems that even a single column Dataframe of Series does not support zero copy automatically. What am I missing?

Comment: Are your single columns of the list type?

Comment: No, simply Float64. But list-like would be nice too, but after reading the answers I doubt it is possible.

Comment: If your df is chunked then that might be why, try `df.rechunk().select('a').to_numpy(allow_copy=False)`. rechunk is itself expensive so probably more like `df=df.rechunk()` then `df().select('a').to_numpy(allow_copy=False)`